# Dealing with interrupted PUT requests in PHP

Tags: php, http, upload, partial

Is it possible to handle partial PUT requests in PHP?

I would like to create a service where clients might upload large files via PUT requests. If they lose their internet connection, I'd like these clients to be able to resume the upload.

**Edit** the given duplicate has *nothing* to do with my question. Please read it or ask me to clarify. What I would like to know is if we can still process HTTP requests in PHP, even if they were interrupted.

Comment: *the given duplicate has nothing to do with my question* -> I don't understand. The question seems exactly the same? (how do I resume a file upload)?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, Ignore the 'resuming' part. The problem I have is that I want the incomplete first request to be handled by PHP. PHP seems to only want to work on fully completed requests. This is a PHP specific question and relates to how the PHP engine works.